# ASP.NET Core publish without ConnectionString

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-migrations

I created *Publish Profile* via *Visual Studio 17*.

To create a *Publish Profile*, I had to put *ConnectionString* in the `appSettings.json` file so that *Visual Studio* would recognize that there was a connection to the database and look for `DbContext`, etc.

I don't want to keep the ConnectionString local, but every time I want to execute *Publish*, I must enter **some** ConnectionString in the `appsetting.json` file, just so that *Visual Studio* will recognize that there is a database that will identify itself the **true** ConnectionString of a database that is in the same ResourceGroup in Azure.

How do I publish with as little as possible maintaining Local ConnectionString, and obviously not in git?

Comment: you can manage secrets in locally called `secrets.json`, you can refer [my article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51871.net-core-2-managing-secrets-in-web-apps.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to publish to an App service?

You can leverage the Keyvault to store secrets and substitute them in runtime.
If you are using Azure DevOps pipelines for deployment, you can update the appsettings during publish.